# Swing UI layout analysis

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am working on extending an application which has a Java Swing GUI. I have extended the business logic and added the required functionality but now I wanted to improve the UI. I have never worked with swing before and the code is not easy to read at all.

Is there any way to analyse/identify the UI components while the application is running? I am using IntelliJ as the IDE.

Comment: why not using javaFX in order to extend UI for java desktop application.

Comment: I have never used javaFX either. There are some custom components which extends JPanel. I am more used to working on android but this is a desktop application.

Comment: i haven't used intellij but in netbeans , there is two files 1 form file corresponding to each UI. you could double click on UI and go through the code (e.g for buttons).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem there are no forms in this application everything has been done dynamically

Comment: JFrame is effectively a "form". Look for classes that extend JFrame. Even if it's being generated dynamically, you can still look through the generation code to see how it's going to be rendered within the UI. And just run it to see what results you get. JavaFX is awesome BTW, look into it :)

Comment: "analyse/identify the UI components." What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using the IntelliJ GUI Builder**

I suggest taking a look at these two websites, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/designing-gui-major-steps.html?origin=old_help) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/gui-designer-basics.html?origin=old_help).

They go over how you can [Set the components properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/setting-component-properties.html?origin=old_help). Doing this could allow you to play around with different foreground and background colors, which could allow you to identify which component is which when you launch the application.

More in depth on the properties can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/components-properties.html)

You can also set the variables names for each component which will allow you to find them easier in the code.

If you are still having troubles locating components in the source code, IntelliJ has a great way to [Search The Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/searching-through-the-source-code.html?origin=old_help) for anything you would like to find.

**If you made the application by hand**

As with the GUI builder, you can set the background colors and such by using something similar to `component.setBackground(Color.BLUE);` to find them easier when the application is ran. You could also give some default elements to something such as a `JTextArea` by using `textArea.setText("My Text");`.

Here are some good read's on [Swing Naming Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770174/name-convention-on-java-swing-componentsprefix) and just [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) in general. This will allow you to layout your code in a cleaner, easier to read fashion.

There's also [this](https://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html) website that goes over what each swing component looks like. You can click each component for more info on it.

As a more general answer, I suggest looking over a couple of the [Oracle Swing Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to get a better overall knowledge of Swing and it's capabilities. I personally don't recommend using GUI builders of any sort. You don't get the same knowledge as you would from doing it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while your program is running to see a dump of the Swing container hierarchy. Compare it to the listings mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305265/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36143833/230513).

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
public static void showStructure(Container container, int depth) {
    Component[] components = container.getComponents();
    StringBuilder indent = new StringBuilder();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < depth; ii++) {
        indent.append("\t");
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < components.length; ii++) {
        System.out.print(indent);
        Component component = components[ii];
        System.out.print(component.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\t");
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            Container c = (Container) component;
            System.out.println(c);
            showStructure(c, depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Used on [this GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556):

[image]

Produces:

```
JRootPane   javax.swing.JRootPane[,8,30,633x454,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
    JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[null.glassPane,0,0,633x454,hidden,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777217,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
    JLayeredPane    javax.swing.JLayeredPane[null.layeredPane,0,0,633x454,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,optimizedDrawingPossible=true]
        JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,633x454,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.TitledBorder@eba654,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
            JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[,5,18,623x54,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.TitledBorder@b30485,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
                JComboBox   javax.swing.JComboBox[,338,21,126x25,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=Metal]
                    MetalComboBoxButton javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton[,106,0,20x25,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=12583208,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=1,bottom=1,right=3],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=false,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                    CellRendererPane    javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
                JCheckBox   javax.swing.JCheckBox[,467,21,148x24,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@628370,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=2,bottom=2,right=2],paintBorder=false,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Pack on PLAF change]
            JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[,5,77,148x372,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.TitledBorder@1d8582e,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
                JButton javax.swing.JButton[,5,18,138x26,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Add Another Label,defaultCapable=true]
                JScrollPane javax.swing.JScrollPane[,5,48,138x319,layout=javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout$UIResource,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$ScrollPaneBorder@1fbebfc,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,columnHeader=,horizontalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1],horizontalScrollBarPolicy=HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,lowerLeft=,lowerRight=,rowHeader=,upperLeft=,upperRight=,verticalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1],verticalScrollBarPolicy=VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,viewport=javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,135x316,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false],viewportBorder=]
                    JViewport   javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,135x316,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]
                        JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,135x316,layout=java.awt.GridLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.TitledBorder@32612b,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
            JSplitPane  javax.swing.JSplitPane[,158,77,470x372,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI$BasicHorizontalLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders$SplitPaneBorder@7f021e,flags=201326920,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,continuousLayout=false,dividerSize=10,lastDividerLocation=0,oneTouchExpandable=false,orientation=VERTICAL_SPLIT]
                JScrollPane javax.swing.JScrollPane[,1,1,468x134,layout=javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout$UIResource,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$ScrollPaneBorder@1e72cd7,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=468,height=134],columnHeader=javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,450x20,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false],horizontalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1],horizontalScrollBarPolicy=HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,lowerLeft=,lowerRight=,rowHeader=,upperLeft=,upperRight=,verticalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,451,21,15x111,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1],verticalScrollBarPolicy=VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,viewport=javax.swing.JViewport[,1,21,450x111,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false],viewportBorder=]
                    JViewport   javax.swing.JViewport[,1,21,450x111,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]
                        JTable  javax.swing.JTable[,0,0,450x896,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=251658568,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,autoCreateColumnsFromModel=true,autoResizeMode=AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS,cellSelectionEnabled=false,editingColumn=-1,editingRow=-1,gridColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=122,g=138,b=153],preferredViewportSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=450,height=400],rowHeight=16,rowMargin=1,rowSelectionAllowed=true,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],selectionForeground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],showHorizontalLines=true,showVerticalLines=true]
                            CellRendererPane    javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,451,21,15x111,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,96,15x15,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,15x15,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                    JViewport   javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,450x20,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]
                        JTableHeader    javax.swing.table.JTableHeader[,0,0,450x20,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777544,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,draggedDistance=0,reorderingAllowed=true,resizingAllowed=true,updateTableInRealTime=true]
                            CellRendererPane    javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
                JScrollPane javax.swing.JScrollPane[,1,145,468x226,layout=javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout$UIResource,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders$ScrollPaneBorder@1fbebfc,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,columnHeader=,horizontalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1],horizontalScrollBarPolicy=HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,lowerLeft=,lowerRight=,rowHeader=,upperLeft=,upperRight=,verticalScrollBar=javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1],verticalScrollBarPolicy=VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,viewport=javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,465x223,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false],viewportBorder=]
                    JViewport   javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,465x223,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=,scrollUnderway=false]
                        JPanel  javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,465x223,layout=java.awt.GridBagLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.TitledBorder@16b8cdc,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
                            JLabel  javax.swing.JLabel[,132,18,200x200,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@98423,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=CENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=VERTICAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                    ScrollBar   javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[,0,0,0x0,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,blockIncrement=10,orientation=HORIZONTAL,unitIncrement=1]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                        MetalScrollButton   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[,0,0,0x0,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@f62048,flags=4194600,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]
                MetalSplitPaneDivider   javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSplitPaneDivider[,1,135,468x10,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneDivider$DividerLayout]
```

Answer (score 0):

To talk more GUI builders: They also tend to generate a lot of code that are difficult to understand. GUI builders might be optimal to create fast GUIs or creating a quick sketch, but they're not recommended for complex GUI as the code becomes harder to maintain. NetBeans' GUI builder is a good example of being simple to use, but generating a lot of uneditable code. Window Builder Pro, on the other hand, does the same, but less messy code than NetBeans' GUI builder, but actually allows you to edit the code it generates.